# Not Uploading photo with .jpg extension using bootstrap validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am uploading photo of ".jpg" extension using bootstrap validation, but its not accepting as .jpg file

plz check my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nxu66ztL/1/)

I have even gone through Bootstrap MIME types..

and also I have tried various options but no success..

**Validation Option 1:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#uploadForm').bootstrapValidator({
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            avatar: {
                validators: {
                    file: {
                        extension: 'jpeg|jpg,png',
                        type: 'image/jpeg,image/png',
                        maxSize: 2048 * 1024,   // 2 MB
                        message: 'The selected file is not valid'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Validation Option 2:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#uploadForm').bootstrapValidator({
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                avatar: {
                    validators: {
                        file: {
                            extension: 'jpeg jpg,png',
                            type: 'image/jpeg,image/png',
                            maxSize: 2048 * 1024,   // 2 MB
                            message: 'The selected file is not valid'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `extension: 'jpeg|jpg,png',` to `extension: 'jpeg,jpg,png',`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nxu66ztL/2/)